# Is deferring a field assignation a race condition?

Tags: go

Consider the following code:

```
type foo struct {
  bar string
}

func f() *foo {
  ret := &foo{"before"}
  defer func() { ret.bar = "after" }()
  return ret
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println(f()) // prints "&{after}"
}
```

The motivation is having to return a struct but some of the fields need to be set only before returning (e.g. a timestamp of when the function completed).

Is deferring the field assignation a race condition?
Is it idiomatic?
Is there a better way?

Comment: There's nothing concurrent here, so there can't be any race.

Comment: @JimB thanks. Is it idiomatic or there's a better way to do this?

Comment: To do what? What is the objective? There's no reason you can't set a variable in a defer statement, but whether it's idiomatic depends on your goal.

Comment: It definitely makes the code less readable and understandable to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks all that commented. For those suggesting to close, may I ask what is unclear in the question? I'm just asking if it's idiomatic to do that or to paste the `ret.bar = "after"` before every `return ret` in the function body.

Comment: It was a bit unclear because your example doesn't seem to do anything useful. It probably would have been more clear to add an `error` case return or something to the function to make it clear what you are doing and why. e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/U6dJw9Z7Cs

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main benefit of using `defer` statement versus invoking something before returning from a function or routine is `defer` will run the statement even when a panic occurs before returning.

Thus it is commonly used to clean up resources (such as closing a file or network connection) rather than to set state.

The function below will not print or return "hello"

```
func f() string {
        panic("omg")
        fmt.Println("hello")
        return "hello"
}
```

This code will print but won't return "hello"

```
func f() string {
        defer fmt.Println("ello")
        panic("omg")
        return "hello"
}
```

To answer your question: No, it won't result in a race. Apart from the above difference, it is equivalent to calling something before the `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You mention timestamping when a function completes. In that case you can use `defer` like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    foo()
}

func foo() {
    defer trace("foo")()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}

func trace(fn string) func() {
    start := time.Now()
    return func() { 
        layout := "15:04:05.000"
        end := time.Now()
        fmt.Printf("%s start at %s, end at %s, total %s", fn, start.Format(layout), end.Format(layout), end.Sub(start))
    }
}
```

Output: `foo start at 23:00:00.000, end at 23:00:01.000, total 1s`